# Выпадающая форма при клике на кнопку

Tags: css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы при клике на кнопочку поиска гостиницы выпадал блок с формой?

Comment: jquery `.show();` или `.css('display','block');`

Comment: Вариантов куча... Все зависит от того, что да как пытаешься реализовать...  Что бы тебе помогли,  выложи хотя бы пример того, что ты хотел сделать, опиши, что у тебя не получилось и какой ты бы хотел окончательный результат...

Answer (score 0):

можно просто класс присвоить нужной конструкции, а в классе уже прописать и позицию и видимость и все что угодно, а когда надобность в конструкции отпадет - удалить класс:

```
.visBlock {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;

    display: block;
}


$(element).addClass('visBlock');
...
$(element).removeClass('visBlock');
```